# expect(x).toMatchSnapshot() -> Use default serialiser or JSON.stringify()?

Tags: javascript, json, snapshot, jestjs

Jest has a [snapshot](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/snapshot-testing.html) feature, and its docs example shows how to use it with React components. (`renderer.create(...).toJSON()`).

When using this feature to test a regular Javascript object, there are two possible ways I have thought of accomplishing this:

- `expect(x).toMatchSnapshot()`

  - this uses the default serialiser
- `expect(JSON.stringify(x, undefined, 2)).toMatchSnapshot()`

  - this uses `JSON.stringify` as the serialiser

Of course, the saved `.snap` file's contents is different in each case; but otherwise they would effectively execute in the same manner.

Which would be considered best practice in this scenario?

Is there yet another recommended way?

Answer (score 1):

There's no best practice. Do what suites you best in your case. If you find your snapshots having more valuable information with `JSON.stringify` go for it.

For complex values (like Vue components or library objects) you may also write your own serializer: http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/configuration.html#snapshotserializers-array-string

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm trying my hand at a dead simple custom serialiser: https://github.com/bguiz/jest-object ... let's see how this works out